# Ultima pasta de um diretório

Tags: delphi, diretório

Como faço para pegar a ultima pasta de um diretório.
Ex:

```
C:\Program Files\Skype
```

A ultima pasta seria Skype.

Comment: Tiago, crie um resposta por favor, funcionou.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para evitar possíveis resultados errados, eu faria da seguinte forma

```
program ConsoleTestApp;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

function ObterNomeUltimaPasta(path: string): string;
var
  pathAjustado: string;
begin
  pathAjustado := path;
  if FileExists(pathAjustado) then
    pathAjustado := ExtractFileDir(pathAjustado);

  Result := ExtractFileName(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(pathAjustado));
end;

begin
  try
    Writeln(ObterNomeUltimaPasta('C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\bz2-1.dll'));
    Writeln(ObterNomeUltimaPasta('C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\'));
    Writeln(ObterNomeUltimaPasta('C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin'));
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

O resultado do console foi

> bin
>   bin
>   bin

Comment: +1 Muito bom, essa é a resposta correta.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode utilizar a função [**`ExtractFileName()`**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.ExtractFileName) para extrair o nome de um arquivo ou pasta, o resultado será os caracteres mais a direita da *string* passada como parâmetro, começando com o primeiro caractere após o [*colon*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dois_pontos) ou [*backslash*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barra_inversa).

Caso o resultado da função acima conter um delimitador no final você pode usar a função [**`ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter()`**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter) para elimina-lo.

```
uses
  SysUtils;

function GetPath(const pPath: string): string;
begin
if ExtractFileExt(pPath) <> '' then
  Result := ExtractFileName(ExtractFileDir(pPath))
else
  Result := ExtractFileName(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(pPath));
end;
```

Para usar:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ShowMessage(GetPath('C:\Program Files\Skype'));            // Skype
ShowMessage(GetPath('C:\Program Files\Skype\'));           // Skype
ShowMessage(GetPath('C:\Program Files\Skype\Skype.exe'));  // Skype
end;
```

Comment: E se eu tiver o path 'C:\Program Files\Skype\'?

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound era essa a ideia mesmo, além de checkar se é um diretório ou arquivo tb ficaria legal

Comment: @Caputo Hoje que fui ver que minha resposta falhava nessa situação. Já arrumei o código. +1

Answer (score 6):

Você precisa de partir a string "C:\Program Files\Skype" nas "\", assim:

```
program Project28;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

procedure Split(Delimiter: Char; Str: string; ListOfStrings: TStrings) ;
begin
   ListOfStrings.Clear;
   ListOfStrings.Delimiter     := Delimiter;
   ListOfStrings.DelimitedText := Str;
end;


var
   OutPutList: TStringList;
begin
   OutPutList := TStringList.Create;
   try
     Split('\', 'C:\Program Files\Skype', OutPutList) ;
     Writeln(OutPutList.Text);
     Readln;
   finally
     OutPutList.Free;
   end;
end.
```

O resultado será:

```
List[0] = 'C:'
List[1] = 'Program Files'
List[2] = 'Skype'
```

Vc só tem de agarrar o List[2] para obter a ultima pasta.

Outra alternativa é usar a função **ExtractFileName**:

```
uses
  SysUtils;

var
    Filepath : string ;
begin
  Filepath:='C:\Program Files\Skype';
  ShowMessage(ExtractFileName(Path));
```

onde o resultado é

```
Skype
```

Comment: uma boa forma de pegar a última pasta seria `List[List.Count-1]`